# If you as a player character get frightened and the caster dies, are you still frightened by the corpse?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, fear

Does the frightened Condition end when the monster you are afraid of dies?

Comment: Different question so not a duplicate but I reckon the answer to this question [Does frightened condition end when you hit 0 HP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96549/14878) will answer this one.

Comment: What is the cause of the frightened condition?

Comment: This is likely to depend on the particular frightening effect. Is there a particular source of fear you are interested in?

Comment: Did you mean "as a player *character*"?

Comment: The frightened condition does not specify when it ends or when it applies, it specifies only what the condition does. So there is no general answer. Perhaps you should ask about a specific monster and quote the text describing how it causes fear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Nothing prevents you from being terrified of a corpse

There just isn't any rule that says you can't be afraid of corpses.. Therefore, if the source of your fear dies, you would still be frightened. However, the source of the frightened condition may matter. For example, the *fear* spell is concentration, so if the caster dies, the spell ends as the caster falls unconscious.

#### But a GM is free to rule otherwise

A GM could argue that Alice's corpse *isn't* Alice at all, so when Bob becomes frightened of Alice for 1 minute, and Alice dies, the source of the fear simply doesn't exist anymore. We lack any general rule that addresses this case, so a GM is well within their rights to rule how they would like.

Comment: Who knows, Alice might be even more scary dead than alive.

Comment: I know I personally would be more scared of a corpse than a live person, and you don't even need a spell for that!

Comment: Alice doesn't _live_ here anymore!

Comment: @Ben pretty sure I already address that: "For example, the fear spell is concentration, so if the caster dies, the spell ends as the caster falls unconscious."

Comment: If source of the fear is a *creature*, and the effect requires *seeing* the creature, then the monster becoming an object (a corpse) would at least stop the negative effects of the condition.

Comment: @Waki That only works if the effect requires actually seeing a *creature* at all. If the effects instead causes fear while some Orc is within sight, a GM would have to rule as to whether the corpse is still the Orc. I mention this in the answer. That said, I don't know any example of a cause of fear that says "While X type of creature is within sight", instead of just saying "While X (a named thing) is within sight". Also worth noting, [a dead creature might still be a creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/114740)